# How does AlarmManager ELAPSED_REALTIME work?

Tags: android

The android documentation( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#ELAPSED_REALTIME ) says **ELAPSED_REALTIME** gives "Alarm time in `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` (time since boot, including sleep)".

But the integer value returned by `AlarmManager`.**ELAPSED_REALTIME** is always 3.
Is **ELAPSED_REALTIME** just a constant value which always remain 3?

Comment: 3 is constant value of `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME`, you have to set this type while configuring your `AlarmManager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! This is a constant, in the docs link you provided, you can see the constant value:

> Constant Value: 3 (0x00000003)

Android API's often use these constant values in their API's. You need to call the API like this:

```
 alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, //other stuff);
```

In this case `ELAPSED_REALTIME` will tell the `AlarmManager` which type of alarm to use. Under the hood this will be just the integer 3.

To let you understand it better, here is the source:

https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/AlarmManager.java#L437, there you can see `@AlarmType int type` which will be used to setup the alarm.

Also see the following property:

```
public static final int ELAPSED_REALTIME = 3;
```